# does redux change the reference of rootState object when a field's value in a sub state changes?

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

i have my redux states setup like this

```
rootState
     subState1
          field1
          field2
     subState2
          field1
          field2
```

multiple sub states inside a root state. if i dispatch an action to change filed2 inside subState1, will redux change the entire rootState object(location of rootState in memory)? if it does so, it'll be performance intensive task. **when i have a large store then it'll make no sense to use redux** cuz on every change it'll replace the rootState object.

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.8.1",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.1",
  }
```

Comment: There is a performance penalty for *very* large stores, theoretically, but generally this is not something you have to worry about. I've worked on an app where we kept hundreds of products' details in redux and there was no performance impact. You're worrying about an implementation detail that the library authors surely must have considered.

Comment: @timotgl seems you're correct, but i wanna know what is actually happening behind the scenes. perhaps i need to look up the source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the root state object is always replaced, because this is a fundamental principle of immutable updates: **an immutable update requires copying *every* level of nesting down to the field that needs to be updated!**

In other words, if I need to update `state.a.b.c.d`, I have to write code like:

```js
return {
  ...state,
  a: {
    ...state.a,
    b: {
      ..state.a.b,
      c: {
        ...state.a.b.c,
        d: newValue
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, I think you are seriously over-estimating the "performance" implications here.  Sure, every JS operation has a cost, and that includes copying objects.  However, copying the *root* state (ie, `{...state}`) typically has almost no cost, because the cost of copying a single object is `O(numFields)`.  In other words, copying an object with 5 fields will be faster than copying an object with 50,000 fields... and a Redux root state object might typically have 5-20 top-level slices (ie, `{users, posts, comments, todos, counter}`, etc).

Generally, reducers are not a perf bottleneck in a Redux app.  Doesn't mean they're *never* a perf issue.  But most of the time it's the cost of updating the UI that actually matters.

Also, per your comment about "wanting to know what's happening behind the scenes":

spoiler:

THERE ISN'T ANYTHING "BEHIND THE SCENES"! :)

Typically, all the logic that *actually* matters in the reducers *is code that you wrote yourself*.  The only code in the `redux` core lib that comes into play here is the `combineReducers` function, and that's just doing the work to help copy and update the root state object.

Comment: thank you for the answer. now i feel more comfortable using redux-toolkit, thanks for that too.

Comment: does redux make use of diffing algorithm to compare the trees and make updates?

Comment: Not within reducers,no.  Every slice reducer is just responsible for returning either the existing state if nothing changed, or a new immutably-updated state if something did change. React-Redux then expects that all state updates are immutable, and uses `===` comparisons to see if extracted values have changed.